# configure: error: Objective C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: objective-c

I'm having trouble installing TikZit. When I run ./configure I get this message:
configure: error: Objective C compiler cannot create executables

Hope you guys can help me. Here is the config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by TikZiT configure 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = rafa-K53E
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.13.0-45-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 13 19:36:28 UTC 2015

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2432: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2500: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2511: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2566: result: yes
configure:2717: checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p
configure:2756: result: /bin/mkdir -p
configure:2763: checking for gawk
configure:2779: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2790: result: gawk
configure:2801: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2823: result: yes
configure:2852: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2869: result: yes
configure:2959: checking whether make supports nested variables
configure:2976: result: yes
configure:3134: checking that generated files are newer than configure
configure:3140: result: done
configure:3148: creating ./config.status

## ---------------------- ##
## Running config.status. ##
## ---------------------- ##

This file was extended by TikZiT config.status 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  CONFIG_FILES    = 
  CONFIG_HEADERS  = 
  CONFIG_LINKS    = 
  CONFIG_COMMANDS = 
  $ ./config.status 

on rafa-K53E

config.status:795: creating Makefile
config.status:795: creating src/Makefile
config.status:795: creating share/Makefile
configure:4244: checking for gcc
configure:4260: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:4271: result: gcc
configure:4296: checking for Objective C compiler version
configure:4305: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:4316: $? = 0
configure:4305: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
configure:4316: $? = 0
configure:4305: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4316: $? = 4
configure:4305: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:4316: $? = 4
configure:4336: checking whether the Objective C compiler works
configure:4358: gcc    conftest.m  >&5
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1obj': execvp: No such file or directory
configure:4362: $? = 1
configure:4400: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "TikZiT"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "tikzit"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "TikZiT 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tikzit"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://tikzit.sourceforge.net"
| #define PACKAGE "tikzit"
| #define VERSION "1.0"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4405: error: in `/home/rafa/tikzit-1.0':
configure:4407: error: Objective C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTK_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTK_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTK_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTK_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_OBJC_set=
ac_cv_env_OBJC_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_PATH_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_path_mkdir=/bin/mkdir
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_OBJC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes
am_cv_make_support_nested_variables=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/rafa/tikzit-1.0/missing aclocal-1.13'
ALLOCA=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='$${TAR-tar}'
AM_BACKSLASH='\'
AM_DEFAULT_V='$(AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY)'
AM_DEFAULT_VERBOSITY='0'
AM_V='$(V)'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/rafa/tikzit-1.0/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/rafa/tikzit-1.0/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/rafa/tikzit-1.0/missing automake-1.13'
AWK='gawk'
CPPFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DEFS='-DPACKAGE_NAME=\"TikZiT\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"tikzit\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"TikZiT\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tikzit\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"http://tikzit.sourceforge.net\" -DPACKAGE=\"tikzit\" -DVERSION=\"1.0\"'
DEPDIR=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
FOUNDATION_LIBS=''
FOUNDATION_OBJCFLAGS=''
GREP=''
GTK_CFLAGS=''
GTK_LIBS=''
HAVE_POPPLER_FALSE=''
HAVE_POPPLER_TRUE=''
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='$(install_sh) -c -s'
LDFLAGS=''
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/rafa/tikzit-1.0/missing makeinfo'
MKDIR_P='/bin/mkdir -p'
OBJC='gcc'
OBJCDEPMODE=''
OBJCFLAGS=''
OBJCPP=''
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='tikzit'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tikzit'
PACKAGE_NAME='TikZiT'
PACKAGE_STRING='TikZiT 1.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='tikzit'
PACKAGE_URL='http://tikzit.sourceforge.net'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=''
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
VERSION='1.0'
WIN32=''
WINDOWS=''
WINDOWS_FALSE=''
WINDOWS_TRUE=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
_WIN32=''
ac_ct_OBJC='gcc'
am__EXEEXT_FALSE=''
am__EXEEXT_TRUE=''
am__fastdepOBJC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepOBJC_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__isrc=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__nodep=''
am__quote=''
am__tar='$${TAR-tar} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='$${TAR-tar} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='${prefix}'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='${SHELL} /home/rafa/tikzit-1.0/install-sh'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='$(MKDIR_P)'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr/local'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "TikZiT"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "tikzit"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "TikZiT 1.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tikzit"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://tikzit.sourceforge.net"
#define PACKAGE "tikzit"
#define VERSION "1.0"
#
#configure: exit 77
```

I've looked for this problem around the forum but it appears there are lots of things that can cause this.

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble with it too. I finally solved the problem by installing gobjc++.

Just run `sudo apt-get install gobjc++` and it worked fine for me.